# String#equals throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException

Tags: java

The stacktrace is quite long but here's the related section.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 33
  at java.lang.String.equals(String.java:1018)
  at java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:305)
```

So, when I retrieve a element from `HashMap<String,?>`, String#equaqls is invoked. Then, an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException thrown from line `if (v1[i++] != v2[j++])`

```
// Sun java 1.6
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
    if (anObject instanceof String) {
        String anotherString = (String)anObject;
        int n = count;
        if (n == anotherString.count) {
            char v1[] = value;
            char v2[] = anotherString.value;
            int i = offset;
            int j = anotherString.offset;
            while (n-- != 0) {
                if (v1[i++] != v2[j++])
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

It's really werid.

---

Update. The exception is get from a log analyze program. And I didn't use reflection there. I also thought about something corrupted the string object but didn't get any clue from code. And this problem didn't reproduce after restarting. I don't know whether it reproduce if I keep retry.

1. LogUtils

   ```
   public static Map<String, String> parseLine(String line) {
       if (StringUtils.isEmpty(line)) {
           return Collections.emptyMap();
       }
       String[] parts = StringUtils.split(line, '\t');
       Map<String, String> results = new HashMap<String, String>();
       for (String part : parts) {
           String[] keyVal = StringUtils.split(part, "=", 2);
           if (keyVal.length == 2) {
               String key = keyVal[0];
               String value = keyVal[1];
               results.put(key, value);
           }
       }
       return results;
   }

   public static void process(String fileName, Date date, Closure closure) throws IOException {
       InputStream is = null;
       Reader r = null;
       try {
           is = new FileInputStream(getFilename(fileName, date));
           is = new BufferedInputStream(is);
           is = new GZIPInputStream(is);
           r = new InputStreamReader(is, "utf8");
           LineIterator iter = IOUtils.lineIterator(r);
           while (iter.hasNext()) {
               String line = iter.nextLine();
               Map<String, String> map = LogUtils.parseLine(line);
               closure.execute(map);
           }
       } finally {
           IOUtils.closeQuietly(r);
           IOUtils.closeQuietly(is);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Closure

   ```
   public void execute(Map<String, String> line) {
       if (dataMap == null) {
           dataMap = new HashMap<String, Map<Long, Integer>>();
       }

       String identifier = line.get(Constants.IDENTIFIER_KEY); // Exception thrown from there
       /* ...blahblah... */
   }
   ```

Just for simple, I will create a closure object and invoke `LogUtils.process` with it. LogUtils break line(Example: `key1=value1\tkey2=value2\t...kn=valuen`) like it into a `HashMap`. Then `LogUtils` will pass the map to the closure. And the Exception is thrown from `line.get(Constants.IDENTIFIER_KEY);` when Constants.IDENTIFIER_KEY is a static final field. So the lhs and rhs of equals method are a static final String and a return value of `StringUtils.split(line, '\t')`. I checked the code of commons-lang. It's a `String#substring` actually. So it still werid.

Comment: That would suggest either i or j is going beyond the limits of that array.

Comment: @veer: I don't think so. Imagine if `n` starts as 0... with your version, it would never terminate.

Comment: @yegong can you show us more code? e.g. insertion and access of the contents of the `Map`.

Comment: @JonSkeet the code of equals method is not my implementation. it's the source of java 1.6.

Comment: @Rhyono sure. but it's java.lang.String#equals. An ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException is not expected here.

Answer (score 2):

This basically suggests that something is corrupting a string object. It's easy enough to reproduce:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String x = "hello";
        String y = new String("xhell");

        Field field = String.class.getDeclaredField("offset");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(y, 1);
        System.out.println(x.equals(y));
    }
}
```

... but we don't know whether that's *actually* the way that the string got corrupted in your situation.

Comment: As the code i paste, there's no reflection. I agree with the corrupted string object. However, the code seems quite simple and nothing is trying to open a String and modify the final field.